# Why is this question considered a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824686/what-is-difference-between-primary-index-and-secondary-index-exactly) is asking about primary and secondary indexes, and it was incorrectly marked as duplicate by some guys who proposed something that has nothing to do with indexes.

For your information, - A single-level index is an auxiliary file that makes it more efficient to search for a record in the data file.

A **primary index** is an **ordered file whose records are of fixed length with two fields**.

1. The first field is of the same data type as the ordering key
   field—called the primary key—of the data file,
2. The second field is a pointer to a disk block (a block address).

A **secondary index** is defined on an unordered data file and can be defined on

1. a key field (with a unique value) or
2. a non-key field with duplicate values

A secondary index is also an ordered file with two fields. The first field is of the same data type as some nonordering field of the data file that is an indexing field. The second field is either a block pointer or a record pointer.

**As you can see, a primary index IS NOT a primary key.**
Please, before you mark a question as duplicate, make sure you understand it first :)

**You should start reading [this](https://books.google.ro/books?id=17D5HEN47nYC&pg=RA1-PA189&lpg=RA1-PA189&dq=Includes%20one%20index%20entry%20for%20each%20block%20in%20the%20data%20file;%20the%20index%20entry%20has%20the%20key%20field%20value%20for%20the%20first%20record%20in%20the%20block,%20which%20is%20called%20the%20block%20anchor&source=bl&ots=B2NpWd4Hi1&sig=sh0CNtYmmA7bzojIShQoa6tpyNA&hl=ro&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBtPPyztjSAhUDwBQKHc7pDXEQ6AEINzAE#v=onepage&q=Includes%20one%20index%20entry%20for%20each%20block%20in%20the%20data%20file%3B%20the%20index%20entry%20has%20the%20key%20field%20value%20for%20the%20first%20record%20in%20the%20block%2C%20which%20is%20called%20the%20block%20anchor&f=false) book :)**

Comment: If you can edit the question without changing the OP's intent to point this out then do so - it'll put the question in the reopen queue. Otherwise, you can leave a *constructive* comment (not the one I've just deleted which didn't required CAPITALS and the last sentence)... - It's also over three years old - does it really, really matter now?

Comment: @JonClements Yes, it DOES matter, because people who want to know about primary and secondary indexes stumble on that question which is pointing to a WRONG resource. This could lead to comfusion.

Comment: @JonClements Of course it still matters. Its age does not mean we should stop caring about correctness.

Comment: That question is incredibly confusing because it has tagged two entirely different technologies that have little to do with each other. The concept of primary & secondary indexes indeed [seems to exist in mySQL.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html) I'm not at all sure that was a bad duplicate closing (but I'm not really a domain expert.)

Comment: @JonClements An edit will only put it in the reopen queue in the first 14 days(while that status is [on hold]).  Once the question is [closed] only a reopen vote will put it into the queue.